Upgrading drupal from 9 to 10: bootstrap subtheme
I have a drupalsite 9.4.x running and I'm trying to upgrade it to 10.
I have installed the upgrade module to check what modules are compatible.
I was able to solve almost every problem, except the part with my bootstrap subtheme.
The module says this about the subtheme:
PHPStan command failed: /data/jail/usr/local/php-8.1/bin/php
/data/sites/web/sitebe/www/vendor/bin/phpstan analyse
--memory-limit=1500M --error-format=json --configuration=/data/sites/web/sitebe/tmp/upgrade_status/deprecation_testing.neon
/data/sites/web/sitebe/www/themes/octopustheme

Command output: Empty.

Command error: PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
router_installer_test_modules_installed() (previously declared in
 /data/sites/web/sitebe/www/core/modules/system/tests/modules/router_installer_test/router_installer_test.module:13)
in
 /data/sites/web/sitebe/www/core/modules/system/tests/modules/router_installer_test/router_installer_test.install
on line 17 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
router_installer_test_modules_installed() (previously declared in
 /data/sites/web/sitebe/www/core/modules/system/tests/modules/router_installer_test/router_installer_test.module:13)
in
 /data/sites/web/sitebe/www/core/modules/system/tests/modules/router_installer_test/router_installer_test.install
on line 17

After searching around I wasn't able to find any information about this.
Do I need to add a hook to my .theme file? The main bootstrap theme doesn't give any error, and my theme is very basic without a lot of modifications. So I don't know why this isn't compatible (Bootstrap 8.x-3.32)
